# VK API wall.get() текст

Tags: php

Ребят, нужна помощь с VK API.

Использую метод `wall.get()` (возвращает список записей со стены сообщества). При выводе текста записи столкнулся с тем, что в нем могут быть куча ссылок и хэштегов и все они хранятся в текстовом виде. То есть ячейка `['text']`, а в ней

> "Что почитать начинающему тимлиду: Василий Половнёв делится материалами, которые хотел бы прочитать в начале пути — http://vasily.polovnyov.ru/posts/team-leadership-links.html #article@forwebdev #russian@forwebdev #collection@forwebdev"

Каким образом сделать, что бы ссылки отображались не как текст, а как ссылка? Регулярным выражением или есть еще какой то способ?

Comment: вк использует викиразметку. Погуглите

Comment: Не совсем понял. Можно чуууть-чуть подробнее пожалуйста.

Comment: @n.osennij в постах на стенах никакая разметка не используется (за исключением ссылок вида [nickname|имя], больше никакой разметки нет)

Comment: @Miracle_Coder да, вам нужно самостоятельно обработать текст любым удобным вас способом, чтобы получить то, что вы хотите. В частности, для поиска ссылок можно найти кучу разных регулярок в интернете

Comment: @andreymal Я пробовал, но то ли я не смог найти нормальные, то ли я что то не так делаю. Вы не могли бы скинуть пример проверенной регулярки? и я так понимаю сначала нужно обрезать все хэштеги, а после искать в тексте ссылки?

Comment: в чем проблема сделать так? https://ideone.com/XlGCyI

Comment: @Jean-Claude оно оборачивает только хэштеги, а ссылки не кликабельны все равно.

Comment: ну так сделай тоже самое для ссылки.

Comment: Кстати, не забудьте защититься от XSS

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так можно решать:

```
$text = 'Что почитать начинающему тимлиду: Василий Половнёв делится материалами, которые хотел бы прочитать';
$text .= 'в начале пути — http://vasily.polovnyov.ru/posts/team-leadership-links.html #article@forwebdev #russian@forwebdev #collection@forwebdev #russian #article';

//ссылки на гипреактивные
$text = preg_replace('%(https?://[^ ]{4,})%isu', '<a href="\1">\1</a>' ,$text);

//хештеги #хештег
$text = preg_replace('%#([^ @]{0,})(?:$|\s)%isu', '<a href="https://vk.com/feed?section=search&q=\1">#\1</a> ' ,$text);

//хештеги с поиском по группе   #russian@forwebdev
$text = preg_replace('%#([^ ]{1,})@([^ ]{1,})%isu', '<a href="https://vk.com/\2/\1">#\1@\2</a>' ,$text);

echo $text;
```

Comment: не корректно отображаются ссылки. перед ними появились хэштеги.

Comment: У меня вот такие требования:
Отображение записей  в виде плиток  (картинка если есть и заголовок со ссылкой на оригинальную запись)
опционально, если к записи прикреплена ссылка, то использовать ее для заголовка.  
все получается вот кроме этого. а до этого с регулярками ни когда не сталкивался. всю ночь бился над этим.

Comment: @Miracle_Coder к сожалению на данном сайте не предъявляют требования.

Comment: у меня не к вам требования, а у меня в задании такие требования.